# Why does isomorphic-style-loader throw a TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined when being used in unison with CSS-Modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, webpack, isomorphic-style-loader

I'm currently trying to render the application on the server, which works for the HTML and JS, but found that my styles (.less | .scss) would not load. I did some research and figured, not sure, that I was missing the `isomorphic-style-loader` in my Webpack configuration based on others running into the same issues. I set it up, at least how I understood it, but am now finding that when running the application I receive the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined at WithStyles.componentWillMount`

I'm somewhat new to the whole React / Express thing but have been trying to follow along with tutorials and learning as I go, if anything seems out of place, please excuse me. I am hoping to see if anybody can explain what exactly causes this error, and provide me with some idea of what I could follow to resolve this error. Below is some example code that resembles the one I am having issues with, if it helps in any way.

(For reference I was following Tyler McGinnis React Router Server Rendering tutorial and tried to expand upon it to add styling - [Link Here](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-server-rendering/))

Thanks beforehand for any explanation provided as to what may be causing this error.

---

#### webpack.config.babel.js

```
import path from 'path'
import webpack from 'webpack'
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals'

const paths = {
  browser: path.join(__dirname, './src/browser'),
  server: path.join(__dirname, './src/server'),
  build: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
}

let browserConfig = {
  entry: `${paths.browser}/index.js`,
  output: {
    path: paths.build,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s?(a|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          'isomorphic-style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          'sass-loader',
          'postcss-loader'
        ]
      }, {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          'isomorphic-style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'less-loader',
            options: {
              javascriptEnabled: true
            }
          },
          'postcss-loader'
        ]
      }, {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __isBrowser__: true
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.sass', '.less']
  }
}

let serverConfig = {
  entry: `${paths.server}/index.js`,
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'server.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s?(a|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          'isomorphic-style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          'sass-loader',
          'postcss-loader'
        ]
      }, {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          'isomorphic-style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'less-loader',
            options: {
              javascriptEnabled: true
            }
          },
          'postcss-loader'
        ]
      }, {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __isBrowser__: false
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.sass', '.less']
  }
}

module.exports = [browserConfig, serverConfig]
```

---

#### server.js

```
import express from "express"
import cors from "cors"
import React from "react"
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import serialize from "serialize-javascript"
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server"
import { StaticRouter, matchPath } from "react-router-dom"
import App from '../shared/App'
import routes from '../shared/routes'

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json()) // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})) // support encoded bodies
app.use(express.static("public"))

app.get("*", (req, res, next) => {
  const activeRoute = routes.find((route) => matchPath(req.url, route)) || {}

  const promise = activeRoute.fetchInitialData
    ? activeRoute.fetchInitialData(req.path)
    : Promise.resolve()

  promise.then((data) => {
    const css = new Set()
    const context = { data, insertCss: (...styles) => styles.forEach(style => css.add(style._getCss())) }
    const markup = renderToString(
      <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
          <App />
      </StaticRouter>
    )

    res.send(`
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>React on the Server!</title>
          <script src="/bundle.js" defer></script>
          <script>window.__INITIAL_DATA__ = ${serialize(data)}</script>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="app">${markup}</div>
        </body>
      </html>
    `)
  }).catch(next)
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is listening on port: ${port}`))
```

---

#### routes.js

```
import AboutMain from './components/About/AboutMain'

const routes =  [
  {
    path: '/about',
    component: AboutMain
  }
]

export default routes
```

---

#### browser.js

```
// Import the neccessary modules for use in file
import React from 'react' // Main React module
import { hydrate } from 'react-dom' // render alternative for server rendering
import App from '../shared/App'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom' // React Router component for client side routing
import '../shared/components/global.scss' // Only has general rules, which do get applied

hydrate(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

---

#### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import routes from './routes'
import { Route, Link, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>    
        <Switch>
          {routes.map(({ path, exact, component: Component, ...rest }) => (
            <Route key={path} path={path} exact={exact} render={(props) => (
              <Component {...props} {...rest} />
            )} />
          ))}
          <Route render={(props) => <NoMatch {...props} /> } />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

---

#### AboutMain.js

```
// Importing Required Modules
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react' // Importing React, Component, Fragment from "react"
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import s from './about.scss'

class AboutMain extends Component {
  state = {
    phrase: 'We Made It!'
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <header className={s.banner}>
          <h1 className={s.heading}>{this.state.phrase}</h1>
        </header>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default withStyles(s)(AboutMain) <-- Error Seems to occur here, at least I think.
```

---

#### about.scss

```
.banner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.heading {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After reviewing the code all night and endlessly searching Google. I found a fix that the main issue with my code was in the `webpack.config.babel.js` setup.

I changed the browser test for sass || scss to use `style-loader`, rather than the `isomorphic-style-loader`. I also removed all `isomorphic-style-loader` logic from my app (ie. `withStyles`, `insertCss`, etc.)

I'm not sure if this was the correct approach, but for the meantime, it seems to fix my problem and does not return any errors or network issues.

Comment: Do share this changes update? I am facing same issue. Thank you

Comment: can you please share with us your end up webpack.config.babel.js ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem went away simply because you removed `isomorphic-style-loader`. Please don't accept your own answer like that. The problem here is you did not provide a `context` so `insertCss.apply(_context, styles)` will complain because `_context` is `undefined`. To solve the problem, follow these steps:

1. Create a `ContextProvider` component in the same directory of `App`

**ContextProvider.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import App from './App'

class ContextProvider extends React.Component {
    static childContextTypes = {
      insertCss: PropTypes.func,
    }

    getChildContext() {
      return { ...this.props.context }
    }

    render () {
      return <App { ...this.props } />
    }
  }

  export default ContextProvider
```

2. Wrap the `ContextProvider` in **BOTH** your `browser.js` and `server.js`. Remember to declare the `context` in both files.

**browser.js** (in other apps, this would be root client code, i.e `client.js` or `index.js`)

```
// Import the neccessary modules for use in file
/* import statements */


const context = {
    insertCss: (...styles) => {
      const removeCss = styles.map(x => x._insertCss());
      return () => {
        removeCss.forEach(f => f());
      };
    },
  }

hydrate(
  <BrowserRouter>
    //ContextProvider wraps around and returns App so we can do this
    <ContextProvider context={context} />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

**server.js**

```
//Additional code above

app.get("*", (req, res, next) => {
  const activeRoute = routes.find((route) => matchPath(req.url, route)) || {}

  const promise = activeRoute.fetchInitialData
    ? activeRoute.fetchInitialData(req.path)
    : Promise.resolve()

  promise.then((data) => {
    const css = new Set()
    const context = { insertCss: (...styles) => 
styles.forEach(style => css.add(style._getCss()))}

    const markup = renderToString(
      <StaticRouter location={req.url}>
        <ContextProvider context={context}> 
         <App />
        </ContextProvider>
      </StaticRouter>
    )

    res.send(`
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>React on the Server!</title>
          <script src="/bundle.js" defer></script>
          <script>window.__INITIAL_DATA__ = ${serialize(data)}</script>
          <style type="text/css">${[...css].join('')}</style>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="app">${markup}</div>
        </body>
      </html>
    `)
  }).catch(next)
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is listening on port: ${port}`))
```

I wrote an article explaining this in more detail here: https://medium.com/@danielnmai/load-css-in-react-server-side-rendering-with-isomorphic-style-loader-848c8140a096